# Why does this code not sort by key?

Tags: python

```
for key in (filedata):
        print(key.strip('\n'))
```

Currently this code prints out the data sorted alphabetically several times. How would i make it sort by key and make it print only once? It needs to sort by the score avg.

Comment: Have you read your code?

Comment: why are you sorting twice? for every line in  sorted(filedata) you are printing every line in  sorted(filedata)

Comment: i have now taken out the 2nd sorted function but it still sorts alphabetically and not by the key of data

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you want to extract the sorting key from each line -- Python can't guess and neither can we, you say "sort by the score avg" but how can we guess **how** you plan to get the score average from each line?!

Supposing for example the score average is the last whitespace-separated word in each line,

```
def score_avg(line):
    return float(line.strip().split()[-1])
```

this might be how you express that notion precisely and unambiguously; then you let Python know:

```
filedata.sort(key=score_avg)
```

(no need to use `sorted` since you're sorting in place!) and you're good to go.

Comment: i may make myself look stupid but im a beginner so go easy on me lol. where would this fit in my code as i cant find it out. Also the score avg is worked out by previous questions in the code

Comment: What "previous questions in the code"?!  Make each question self-sufficient -- no way people are going to chase through previous questions you asked and try to figure out which ones are needed to understand your question!  As for "where it fits": the `key=score_avg` fits where your Q previously had a call to `sorted` that you've now mysteriously deleted, and the `def` of whatever function you're going to be passing as `key=` fits anywhere before that.